# jQuery REST Results = "[object Object],[object Object] etc"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

We are hiding the List GUI from our visitors on some landing pages in SharePoint Foundations 2013 and displaying instead REST data harvested from the applicable lists.

Since SharePoint's REST has a 100 record limit, I am testing for the __next object and recursively calling the GET until all the list has been harvested.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
var test = {
    root_url: "http://" + document.domain,

    init: function(){
        // Just some styling
        $('.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contentBox').css('margin-left', '0' );

        // Event Handlers
        $('#btnGoHome').on('click', this.showHome);
        $('#corp_search').on('focus', this.getAllCorp);
    },

    getAllCorp: function(){
        $('#event_listing').html("");
        test.getListItems( test.root_url + "/humanresources/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Corporate Directory')/items?$select=FirstName,Title&$orderby=Title asc", '#news_listing' );
    },

    getListItems: function(pURL, loc){
        $(loc).html("");
        var listDeferred = $.ajax({
            url: pURL,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        $.when(listDeferred).done(function(data){
            var msg;
            $('#event_listing').append(data.d.results.toString());
            msg = data.d.results.length;

            //msg.append(data.d.results);

            if(data.d.__next){
                msg += 'still got more!';
                var url = data.d.__next;
                test.getListItems( url, loc );
            } // end if

            $(loc).append(msg);
        });
        },

        showHome: function(){
        $('body').append('HOME');
        }
};

$(document).ready( function(){
    test.init();
});
```

The "news_listing" div shows me my recursive calls are working:

```
100still got more!27
```

However, rather than the list contents, the other div returns:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object][object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

There's 127 of them so I am returning the list results. HOW do I turn that into something I can pass to a Handlebars template for proper display?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not just turn data.d.results on a string. You must make a grab for For all results that return in data.d.results. 
So you will have:

```
for(var i = 0; i<data.d.results.length; i++){
     $('#event_listing').append(data.d.results[i].ID);
     $('#event_listing').append(data.d.results[i].Title);
}
```

So you return the ID and title of all objects, since you have an array of objects and each object is an item, each item has its fields like: ID, Title, Author, and so on. 
You must give a console.log(data.d.results[i]) to see what each object brings.

Comment: So my return object is an object(object(object(arrayofObjects)))?

Comment: array[object, object,object, object], many objects into the array. If you do FOR as I said, you will have access to an object at a time. So you can get the values ​​of each field as my example.

Comment: yes, I tested it and it works. Now I have to figure out how to make pass it into a Handlebars template

Comment: If it worked please mark as answer. For any other questions just open a new topic, if I can help I will help.

Comment: One quick question -- in the loop if I create a new object with the necessary values, can I "return" that object to getAllCorp where I can call the Handlebars template? The reason I ask this is I have 4 other similar calls on the page, so I am trying to make it modular and DRY and not rewrite the $.Ajax for each. (If you think this is a new question, I will mark you right and start another).

Comment: You want to modify the object and send it back to sharepoint?

Comment: no, send it back to the referring function

Comment: Yes, you can create a function that takes the object and data.d.results FOR perform this function. Just be careful with the asynchrony of JQuery (if you are using). Feel free to mount a function of the way that best suit you.